# How can i make wordpress blog title clickable and direct to the post itself

Tags: get-the-title

How can i make wordpress blog event titles clickable and direct to their respective post itself? Thank you!

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'stm_post_info' ); ?>>
<?php if( get_the_title() ): ?>
    <h4 class="stripe_2"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'stm_post_info' ); ?>>
<?php if( get_the_title() ): ?>
    <h4 class="stripe_2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please try this

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below one :

```
<li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'stm_post_info' ); ?>>
<?php if( get_the_title() ): ?>    <h4 class="stripe_2"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4><?php endif; ?>
```

that is more specific with particular post